# Issue on adding SSH key to GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, ecdsa

I have got an issue that seems about the format of SSH key used by GitHub. I used [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) to generate a new SSH key:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "youremail@youremail.com"
```

Then, I copied the key to the SSH section in settings of my GitHub account page. However, it came with the issue notice as follows:

```
Key is invalid. It must begin with 'ssh-ed25519', 'ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384', or 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp521'. Check that you're copying the public half of the key
```

Following that, I edited my SSH key starting with ssh-rsa and my email address at the end. However, the issue is still there.

What is the solution to this?

Comment: Looks like it has happened with you, because you've tried to add your private key instead of public one

Comment: make sure it's the id_rsa.pub

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68192584/7942242

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply follow these steps and you will set up your SSH key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How can I add the SSH key to the GitHub account?

- Login to the GitHub account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (*Settings*)

  [image: GitHub account settings]
- Click on the <kbd>SSH keys</kbd>

  [image: SSH key section]
- Click on the <kbd>Add SSH key</kbd>

  [image: Add SSH key]
- Paste your key and save

And you are all set to go :-)

Comment: Easy way to grab this key to copy/paste into GitHub is using their suggested: `clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` command

Comment: For those of us who make things harder than they have to be, also ensure that you are using the text from the .pub file.

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Answer (score 34):

`ssh-keygen` will generate you a pair of keys, one private and one public. It sounds like you uploaded the wrong one. GitHub wants the public key, typically here: `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, I just found one ending with .pub so that is the right and works properly!

Comment: Wow. This was my problem as well. I feel like a donkey. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a Mac and are ***typing out*** GitHub's instructions (e.g. *[Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)*, you're probably typing and ***only tabbing*** (e.g. auto-completing) to:

> $ pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa

and not

> $ pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

With the former you're actually copying, and trying to paste your *private key*.

I hope that saves you some time.

Comment: sometimes I feel like a nut. sometimes I don't.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to copy the public key to the clipboard:

```
clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: What platform? [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)? Is `clip` installed by default?

Answer (score 2):

Open file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Then open it with an editor and copy the public key to your GitHub account.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and it turns out it was due to there being a `-` in the comment. GitHub apparently doesn't like `-`, but `_` is OK though.

Answer (score 1):

Add SSH key to Github

Check if you have a key?

```
ssh-add -l
```

If not? then follow steps to generate key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C your__gmail
```

Now for copy the key use xclip tool or just goto file and copy

```
sudo apt install xclip
xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

- Now goto github.com and goto settings
- select  SSH and GPG keys
- New SSH key
- Enter "your__choice__name" in title field...
- Paste your public key into the Key field
- Click Add SSH key

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliJ IDE,

Go to **IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences...**
[image]