# Intellij IDE can't import project from gitHub

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I can't seem to import a project from gitHub. I get an error message saying:

"Clone failed: unable to access 'https://github.com/myGitHubUsername/projectName.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:"

I've heard people have this error before, but the key difference is that my intellij doesn't specify what locations. The console pasted above was Ctrl+A, so I'm 100% sure that I didn't just miss the text. It doesn't say what the problem is.
When I try to checkout from VCS on the intellij start screen, I test the URL and just get the response that "Repository test has failed".

What's causing the problem?

I have git installed and my email set in git-bash.
I'm running Intellij 2016.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your certificate is outdated, that's why.

The easiest solution is to switch to ssh protocol (`git://`) after setting up the ssh keys.

Once you setup the keys and after adding them to the github account change the clone protocol and you will be able to clone and work.

Comment: You need to create a new one. it has expiration date

Comment: I might sound really dumb, but how do i create a new Certificate?

Comment: Switch to ssh protocol instead.read this on how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612504/issue-on-adding-ssh-key-to-github/35612800#35612800