# Travis CI error when try to push changes to github

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am repeatedly getting this

```
Error: Command failed: `git push --set-upstream origin gh-pages`  
remote: Invalid username or password.  
fatal: 
    Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/kathirr007/myrepo-to-test.git/'
```

Someone please help me to setup right setup for travis ci to push changes to github

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with travis-CI.

You are using `https` which require password for every action which involve the server side (`pull`,`push`,`fetch`).

Switch to SSH and you will have to type in your passwords again.

Read here how to do it.
[Issue on adding SSH key to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612504/issue-on-adding-ssh-key-to-github/35612800#35612800)

---

You can first test your github connection regardless of the protocol you are using

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Then setup the remote instead of using the upstream

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ssh keys, you can also use an encrypted github access token. 
Either way you need to add some form of encrypted, passwordless  authorization to your repo. Maybe have a look [here](https://gist.github.com/domenic/ec8b0fc8ab45f39403dd)

Comment: do you know where I can find the SSH key on Travis CI?